# Scala mailboxsize is 0 after receiving 7 messages

Tags: multithreading, scala, actor

I'm new to Scala and I'm trying to understand multithreading with actors.
I wrote this piece of code and I don't understand some behaviour.

```
package sum
import scala.actors.Actor._

object ActorTest extends App {

  val caller = self

  val firstActor = actor {
    Thread.sleep(3000)
    println("Messages in mailbox: " + mailboxSize)
    receive {
      case x => println("First actor received: " + x)
    }
    println("Messages in mailbox: " + mailboxSize)
  }

  for(i <- 1 to 7)
  {
    firstActor ! "Hello" + i
    println("Message sent")
  }
}
```

this is the output:

```
Message sent
Message sent
Message sent
Message sent
Message sent
Message sent
Message sent
Messages in mailbox: 0
First actor received: Hello1
Messages in mailbox: 6
```

I don't understand why the first time, the messages in mailbox is 0, and the second time the messages in mailbox is 6 because all the messages are sent while the thread was asleep.
I think I'm misunderstanding something. Can someone give me an explanation of this behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: Switch to Akka. The old Scala actor library is deprecated and inferior.

Comment: What do you mean? It's a bug in Scala or so? It looks like Akka is another language...

Comment: Akka is not a language. It is a concurrent and distributed programming framework that includes a vastly improved implementation of Actors that can be used from Scala or Java. Its implemetation of futures are now (since 2.10) the Scala Standard Library futures.

Comment: @RandallSchulz funny to hear [*switch to akka*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question) because [akka prohibit access to mailbox size](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Qf3275Z0En8J:letitcrash.com/post/17707262394/why-no-mailboxsize-in-akka-2+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk) :-) not saying that such functionality is not nasty, but it will not solve op's problem directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Untested and mostly guessed. I have never used Scala actors*

I think it's an implementation detail. To me it's unclear when the body of the function passed to the `actor` function is executed.

It seems that it regards the mailbox as empty as long as you have not defined a `recieve` function. The `recieve` function is executed asynchronously, so I would recommend you to check the mailbox from within that function.

```
val firstActor = actor {
  receive {
    case x => 
      println("First actor received: " + x)
      println("Messages in mailbox: " + mailboxSize)
  }

  Thread.sleep(3000)
  println("Messages in mailbox: " + mailboxSize)
}

for(i <- 1 to 7)
{
  firstActor ! "Hello" + i
  println("Message sent")
}
```

I guess that the above code would print something similar to this:

```
Message sent
Message sent
Message sent
Message sent
First actor received: Hello2
Messages in mailbox: 4
Message sent
Message sent
First actor received: Hello1
Messages in mailbox: 6
...
Messages in mailbox: 6
```

Note that the output may be quite different as I can not predict in what order and at what speed the actor system handles messages.

As other said in comments, when you work with actors, the recommended library is [Akka](http://akka.io/)